# "List index out of range" error

Tags: python, list, range

I am writing a program in Python that will take a snippet of binary and encrypt it according to a key. If the snippet is shorter than the key, it has to take the last bit of the key, hence the double reverse. My problem comes when trying to add the last piece of the key to a blank list,  where it gives me the "list index out of range" error. Code is as follows:

```
def OTP(msg,clave):
encList = []
encr = ''
clist = list(clave)
clist.reverse()
cutlist = []
mlist = list(msg)
mlist.reverse()
for i in range(len(msg)):
    cutlist.append(clist[i])
for i in mlist:
    for j in cutlist:
        if i == j:
            encList.append(0)
        if 1 != j:
            encList.append(1)
encList.reverse()
for i in encList:
    encr += str(encList[i])
return encr

clave = '000000010011010010001001000110110011001101010011100101010000101100111110000010100000011010010000101100000101100011010110100000100110001011001101101110110101000010000010100101000101101101010010001100001100100010111111111110010011101110010101110100111110000001101111110010000000101011000101111110100100101000110010111001100110011010100011011001101010011111100101'
msg = '01101000011010000110100001101000'

cript = OTP(msg,clave)
rev = OTP(cript,clave)
print(rev)
```

I am giving it the range of the length of the message, which should be within the range of the much longer key. As always, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python (sorry, forgot to mention). I tried pieces of the code separately, and they worked fine.

Comment: _"If anyone wants to know how (or wants me to delete this question), just tell me."_ Yes, either one of these is fine, thanks. I just hate to see a question go unanswered :-)

Comment: If you've already solved the issue, please post the answer below for future users to learn from

Comment: A self-answer is always appreciated as it shows future visitors of the question who might have a similiar problem how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose because by using a double `for` loop gave me a list with a number of items equal to the length of `msg` squared, because it considered each item in `mlist`times each item in `cutlist`.

This meant that when the function was called a second time (to decrypt the message and confirm the program worked), the `msg` argument was much longer than the `clave` argument, cre an error. To fix this, a single `for` loop with `range(len(msg))` as a parameter can be used, and added 0 or 1 to `encr` depending on whether `cutlist[i] == mlist[i]`.

Comment: This is just an answer from the question, to leave the question but to make sure it did not go unanswered. For the author, please either accept, create your own answer or delete the question.