# How to make the none dissapear in this function?

Tags: python

Hi I have problems because this function creates the numbers which I wanted but also generates a `None`. How should I write this code to not produce the NONE

```
def binary (str):
    b = []
    for x in str:
        b.append(format(ord(x), 'b'))
    return ((b))
clave = "1001001000010001001000110111111100110000100011001010100000110001110110011111010010011111000011111001000011101011001101000001110010011110010110000000"

c = list(clave)
msg = binary("Lol")
print("".join(msg))
m = list("".join(msg))
print("Now the right")

def OTP(m,c):    
    for i in range (0,len(m)):
        if c[i]== "1" and m[i]== "1":
            m.pop(i)
            m.insert(i,"0")
        elif c[i] == "1" and m[i] == "0":
            m.pop(i)
            m.insert(i,"1")
    return print("".join(m))

msg1 = OTP(m,c)
print(msg1)
```

Comment: This can't be your code: once I fixed the indentation for you you can see from the highlighting that you have an unmatched quote on one line. Please copy and paste your actual code.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - are you and Rafael on the same course? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497000/list-index-out-of-range-error

Answer (score 3):

The reason OPT returns none is because you return the return result of the print function  -

```
return print("".join(m))
```

Which is indeed None. To obtain the string you should just do -

```
return "".join(m)
```